# Executing python from swift via bash: "can't open file...[Errno 1] Operation not permitted"

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, swift-pythonkit

I am learning how to make apps for mac, and I am starting with an app to manage my many discord bots. Essentially, the goal is to have many switches to turn bots on and off, which requires executing the python files for the bots, written using `discord.py`. I read about a `PythonKit` module for swift, but when I tried to run a discord bot from the files using that, the build continuously failed, so I decided to use the bash shell to excecute the python. Here is my swift code for using bash shell commands:

```swift
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()

        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        return output
    }func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()

        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        return output
    }
```

I then called `shell("/usr/local/bin/python3.9 path/to/file.py")`, and made it print the output to the console. This was the output:
`/usr/local/bin/python3.9: can't open file 'path/to/file.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`. I am running this from both AppCode and Xcode, and made sure to give both of those apps full disk access, as well as giving terminal full disk access to be sure. In addition, I tried running `/usr/local/bin/python3.9 path/to/file.py`in my terminal, and it works fine. What is happening here? Why can swift not open this file in the bash shell while I can? What do I do to fix it? Let me know if you need more info(if you think PythonKit is the answer, I'll send the build error info from that to debug that process)
Thanks!

Comment: I got a feeling it is related to app sandboxing: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox

Comment: UPDATE: I gave the application I was making full disk access itself, and it still gave the same error. It looks like sandboxing is off by default, but I haven't checked the sandboxing status of this project.

Comment: @NathanWolf : What happens if you replace the relative path to `file.py` to an abolute one? Also - for debugging - run a `stat .../path/to/file.py` in both contexts (your script and your terminal) and check that the inode numbers are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yonatan Vainer was right, turns out sandboxing was on in the entitlements file, so I had to set it to off, which fixed it.